# Angular routing via ng-template

Tags: angularjs, routes

Hi What wrong am i doing. I am new to angular js and i am using ng-template for routing withing the views.

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationPro    vider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'add.html',
        controller: 'myAppCtrl'
      }).
      when('/edit',{
        templateUrl:'edit.html',
        controller:'myAppCtrl'
      }).
       otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   }]);
}])
```

But its not working. Please help me .

below is my part of html

```
<body ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
<div ng-view>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="add.html">
<div>
<input type="text" ng-model="$storage.myname"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="$storage.myid"/>
<input type="number" ng-model="$storage.mynumber"/>
<button ng-click="submit();"> submit </button>
</div>
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: in your function you have "$locationPro    vider" - is that space in your actual code or just here?

Comment: sorry, its just a space when i posted the question here.But the real problem is else where

Comment: I'm news to this too, but have you declared the app (myApp in the javascript) in you html? - ng-app="myApp"

Comment: @user602088: i am new but i have covered the basic things,my url is file:///E:/angular/index.html#/ . Routing does happen but my view in ng-template is not getting rendered

Comment: do you noot need to declare the app in the hTmL like thay show here https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02 - in your case add ng-app="myApp" to the HTML or BODY tag?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a couple of things:

1. The controller that you defined in your body (`ng-controller="my AppController"`) is also defined as controller for the route. I suspect you want one or the other but not both.
2. Your script tag containing the template is inside the div that it will replace (`<div ng-view>`). The ng-view div should be empty (`<div ng-view></div>`)and the template defined outside of it, possibly in the header.

Comment: sorry that was a typo for the controller name.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your code, got solution for your routing here is working fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9porswhz/)
Here is code

```
//html
    <div ng-app="app">
      <div ng-controller="MainCntl">
        Choose:
          <a href="/add">add</a> |
          <a href="/edit">Edit</a> |
        <div ng-view></div>
        <hr />
          <pre>$location.path() = {{$location.path()}}</pre>
     </div>
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="add.html">
        Add
      </script>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit.html">
       Edit
      </script>
    </div>
//app.js

    var myApp = angular.module('app', [], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
      .when('/add', {
        templateUrl: 'add.html',
        controller: MainCntl
      })
      .when('/edit', {
        templateUrl: 'edit.html',
        controller: MainCntl,
      });
         // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
    function MainCntl($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
    }
```